# How can I convert JSON boolean values for output using XMLout?

Tags: perl, json, xml-simple

There are boolean values in the JSON data structure I am using. When call `decode_json` to convert it to a Perl data structure and feed to the `XMLout` function provided by `XML::Simple`, it throws an error because `XMLout` does not know how to deal with `JSON::XS::Boolean` values.

Is there a way to convert the `JSON::XS::Boolean` values in a data structure to XML?

```
my $text = '{"a":"x","b":true}'; 
my $result = decode_json($text);
my $rec = XMLout( $result, RootName => 'root', SuppressEmpty => 1);
```

In the code abive, I get the following error - *Can't encode a value of type: JSON::XS::Boolean*

A `print Dumper $result` gives:

```
$result = {
        'a' => 'x',
        'b' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' )
      };
```

Comment: Your question is not about JSON but it is about how to get XML::Simple to recognize the JSON boolean value and encode it in its output. You should re-write this question so it makes sense because I don't think I should go in and change the whole thing. Also, haven't you heard of single quotes in Perl? my $text = '{"a" : "x", "b": true}'; Why make it hard for others to read your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the [same question on PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=773713) and am reproducing the proposed solution below.

Basically, the solution is to change the value of JSON::XS::Boolean to an appropriate value before passing it to XMLout:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use XML::Simple;

my $text = '{"a":"x","b":true}';
my $result = decode_json($text);

for my $value ( values %$result ) {
    next unless 'JSON::XS::Boolean' eq ref $value;
    $value = ( $value ? 'true' : 'false' );
}

print XMLout( $result, RootName => 'root', SuppressEmpty => 1);
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> test.pl
<root a="x" b="true" />
```

Comment: Note that you do not need `each`, only `values`.

Comment: I would change the condition to not to rely on an implementation detail. Use JSON::is_bool($scalar) instead.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** I wrote this answer before all the edits to the original question. The question as stated now is that the original poster wants to create an XML-ready structure for using with XML::Simple; originally stated, it seemed that he just wanted to put the JSON structure in a text node.

Perl objects need to be JSON-encoded before sending them through the wire.

From your example:

```
my $text = '{"a":"x","b":true}'; 
my $result = decode_json($text);
print JSON->new->utf8->pretty(1)->encode($result);
```

You get the following:

```
$ perl json.pl 
{
   "a" : "x",
   "b" : true
}
```

Comment: And what do you think he will get when he passes that output to XML::Simple::XMLout?